# Automation Process to Copy from Word Doc to Another Word

Tags: ms-word

I have two Word documents

1. First word doc  contains 3 tables.
2. Second word doc contains some paragraphs. And the titles "Table1", "Table2", and "Table3".

I would like to paste table 1 from word doc #1 under "Table1" of doc #2 and so on. I tried the copy, and paste RTF  link but the link gets broken when I update it.
Is there another way to do this?

Comment: You can do this with VBA: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff604039(v=office.14).aspx To help you more you have to give more Information and code.

Comment: Why have you tagged this as "excel" - wouldn't this be a "ms-word" (and probably "vba" and "word-vba") question?  It definitely isn't related to computer memory sizes, so I have replaced "word" with "ms-word" for you.